# Handlebars & Js | Why is my event not executing the referenced child function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, handlebars.js

**SUMMARY:** I am creating a design portfolio in html/scss/js, and instead of creating an html file for each project, I've created one display.html. I spent some time learning React.js, and decided to try to create a more efficient site by using templating (handlebars.js). This is my first time applying handlebars.js, and it doesn't seem too unrealistic of a challenge.

**EXPECTED:** On my index.html page, the user can select 1 of 5 projects, firing the corresponding `onclick` event. That will then redirect to display.html, and display the information corresponding to the selection.

```
<li class="portfolio">
     <a href="/display.html" onclick="firstLink()">Project1</a>
</li>
<li class="portfolio">
     <a href="/display.html" onclick="secondLink()">Project2</a>
</li> . . . etc.
```

Display.html is where the template is, and should load based on which function is selected from index.html. Both pages reference template.js, where I store all the template data. If I omit `function firstLink()`, I can load a single object(`first = {}`). In that regards, I know that the issue is in the template.js file. template.js is as follows:

```
$(function() {
let templateScript = $("#expressions-template").html();

let theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(templateScript);

function firstLink() {
    let first = {
        "project": {
            "name": "Project 1",
            "type": "Website Redesign" };

    let theCompiledHtml = theTemplate(first);
    $('.content-placeholder').html(theCompiledHtml);
```

**PROBLEM:** However, using this method, display.html remains blank. If I put `firstLink();` after the last line of the snippet, the page loads. That is incorrect, as it needs to be corresponding to the user selection. 
If I put `console.log("loaded");` in line 2 of the template.js, it runs successfully. *However, the `function firstLink()` does not.*

**CONSIDERATIONS:** After looking at the [partials documentation](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#partials), I am wondering if I should be handling this process with handlebars rather than writing my own function.

**QUESTION:** What route or resources should I consider to successfully fire the corresponding `onclick` event from index.html and load on display.html, referencing template.js?

Comment: It is not clear to me what `template.js` is/does.

Comment: @76484 template.js is all the content that will display on display.html. Display.html has, for example,`{{project.name}}, {{project.type}}`, etc. template.js has objects for each project. `first = { "project": { "name": "project 1", "type":"website redesign"}}, second = { "project": {"name":"project 2", "type": "app design"}}`, etc. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @76484 so `<a href="" onclick="firstLink()">` corresponds to project one: `first = { "project":{ "name":"project 1" } }` and `<a href ="" onclick=secondLink()">` corresponds to project two: `second = { "project"" {"name":"project2"}}`

Comment: It looks like when I click any link in `index.html`, the browser is going to navigate me to `display.html`. So it doesn't really matter what code you have executing in `firstClick` and `secondClick` because nothing that is done in these functions is going to persist when `display.html` is loaded.

Comment: @76484 I felt like maybe that was the problem. Is there a way to work around that, or would it be best to make a html page for each link in `index.html` ?

Comment: You could specify which content to load in the query string, ex. `/display.html?content=first`. Then display.html would lookup the correct data object based on the query param and then pass that to the template function and render the result. No `firstLink`, `secondLink`, ... functions neccessary.

Comment: @76484 That worked! I set each href to `?content=first`, `?content=second`, etc. and then created an if-statement in template.js: `if(window.location.href.indexOf("first")>-1) { theCompiledHtml = theTemplate(first); } else if etc.`